# Scheme: Split list into list of two sublists of even and odd positions

Tags: scheme, racket

I'm trying to use direct recursion to sort a list into a list of sublists of even and odd positions.

So (split '(1 2 3 4 5 6)) returns ((1 3 5) (2 4 6))

and (split '(a 2 b 3)) returns ((a b) (2 3))

So far, I have the following code:

```
(define split
  (lambda (ls)
    (if (or (null? ls) (null? (cdr ls))) 
        (values ls '())
        (call-with-values
          (lambda () (split (cddr ls)))
          (lambda (odds evens)
            (values (cons (car ls) odds)
                    (cons (cadr ls) evens)))))))
```

However, now I'm stumped on how to store multiple outputs into a single list.

I know that calling it like this:

```
(call-with-values (lambda () (split '(a b c d e f))) list)
```

returns a list of sublists, however I would like the function itself to return a list of sublists. Is there a better way to do this that doesn't involve the use of values and call-with-values?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure. Here's an adapted version of your code:

```
(define (split ls)
  (if (or (null? ls) (null? (cdr ls)))
      (list ls '())
      (let ((next (split (cddr ls))))
        (list (cons (car ls) (car next))
              (cons (cadr ls) (cadr next))))))
```

Comment: Thanks, this approach seems much cleaner.

Comment: @benrudgers It _does_ include the last value among the odds. Have you run the code? :-)

Comment: That level of intelligence is really asking too much.

Answer (score 0):

One thing that I like about the code in the question is that it uses `odds` and `evens` in a way that reflects the specification.

The objectives of this solution are:

1. Readability.
2. To reflect the language of the specification in the code.
3. To use O(n) space during execution.

It uses an internal function with accumulators and a trampoline.

```
#lang racket

;; List(Any) -> List(List(Any) List(Any))
(define (split list-of-x)

  (define end-of-list (length list-of-x))

  ;;  List(Any) List(Any) List(Any) Integer -> List(List(Any) List(Any))
  (define (looper working-list odds evens index)
    (cond [(> index end-of-list)
           (list (reverse odds)
                 (reverse evens))]
          [(odd? index)
           (looper (rest working-list)
                   (cons (car working-list) odds)
                   evens
                   (add1 index))]
          [(even? index)
           (looper (rest working-list)
                   odds
                   (cons (car working-list) evens)
                   (add1 index))]
          [else
           (error "split: unhandled index condition")]))

  (looper list-of-x null null 1))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an answer that should be clear if you are familiar with `match` syntax. It is identical in form and function to Chris Jester-Young's answer, but uses `match` to clarify list manipulation.

```lisp
#lang racket

(define (split ls)
  (match ls
    [`(,first ,second ,rest ...) 
     (match (split rest)
       [`(,evens ,odds) (list (cons first evens)
                              (cons second odds))])]
    [_ (list ls '())]))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(: split ((list-of natural) -> (list-of (list-of natural))))
(define split
  (lambda (xs)
    (list (filter even? xs) (filter odd? xs))))

(: filter ((%a -> boolean) (list-of %a) -> (list-of %a)))
(define filter
  (lambda (p xs)
   (fold empty (lambda (first result)
                   (if (p first)
                       (make-pair first result)
                       result)) xs)))

(check-expect (split (list 1 2 3 4 5 6)) (list (list 2 4 6) (list 1 3 5)))
```

i think this one is also really easy to understand..